# How to show and hide UIAlertAction buttons using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uialertaction

I am implementing navigation bar button click to show `UIAlertAction` with multiple `buttons`. Here, I  need to show and hide UIAlertAction buttons based on `Switch` case input value matching. 
I tried below code but don’t know how to `hide` and `show` UIAlertAction buttons. How to achieve this?

My Code Below

```
@IBAction func ClickAction(_ sender: Any) {


        var index = 100
        switch index {
        case 100  : break
            // Show Actionsheet button 1 & 2
        case 10  : break
            // Show Actionsheet button 4
        case 5  : break
            // Show Actionsheet button 3
        default : break
            // Show Actionsheet button 1 & 3
        }


        let actionSheetAlertController: UIAlertController = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: nil, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)

        let cancelActionButton = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
        actionSheetAlertController.addAction(cancelActionButton)

        // Button #1
        let oneActionButton = UIAlertAction(title: "One", style: .default, handler: {(action:UIAlertAction!) in
            print("One")
        })
        actionSheetAlertController.addAction(oneActionButton)
        oneActionButton.setValue(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "usa.png"), forKey: "image")
        oneActionButton.setValue(CATextLayerAlignmentMode.left, forKey: "titleTextAlignment")

        // Button #2
        let twoActionButton = UIAlertAction(title: "Two", style: .default, handler:{(action:UIAlertAction!) in
            print("Two")
        })
        actionSheetAlertController.addAction(twoActionButton)
        twoActionButton.setValue(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "usa.png"), forKey: "image")
        twoActionButton.setValue(CATextLayerAlignmentMode.left, forKey: "titleTextAlignment")

        // Button #3
        let threeActionButton = UIAlertAction(title: "Three", style: .default, handler:{(action:UIAlertAction!) in
            print("Three")
        })
        actionSheetAlertController.addAction(threeActionButton)
        threeActionButton.setValue(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "usa.png"), forKey: "image")
        threeActionButton.setValue(CATextLayerAlignmentMode.left, forKey: "titleTextAlignment")

        // Button #4
        let fourActionButton = UIAlertAction(title: "Four", style: .default, handler:{(action:UIAlertAction!) in
            print("Four")
        })
        actionSheetAlertController.addAction(fourActionButton)
        fourActionButton.setValue(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "usa.png"), forKey: "image")
        fourActionButton.setValue(CATextLayerAlignmentMode.left, forKey: "titleTextAlignment")

        actionSheetAlertController.view.tintColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.317096545, green: 0.5791940689, blue: 0.3803742655, alpha: 1)
        self.present(actionSheetAlertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the button to the alert inside the switch

```
        let actionSheetAlertController: UIAlertController = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: nil, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)

        let cancelActionButton = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
        actionSheetAlertController.addAction(cancelActionButton)

        // Button #1
        let oneActionButton = UIAlertAction(title: "One", style: .default, handler: {(action:UIAlertAction!) in
            print("One")
        })
        oneActionButton.setValue(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "usa.png"), forKey: "image")
        oneActionButton.setValue(CATextLayerAlignmentMode.left, forKey: "titleTextAlignment")




        // Button #2
        let twoActionButton = UIAlertAction(title: "Two", style: .default, handler:{(action:UIAlertAction!) in
            print("Two")
        })
        twoActionButton.setValue(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "usa.png"), forKey: "image")
        twoActionButton.setValue(CATextLayerAlignmentMode.left, forKey: "titleTextAlignment")

        // Button #3
        let threeActionButton = UIAlertAction(title: "Three", style: .default, handler:{(action:UIAlertAction!) in
            print("Three")
        })
        threeActionButton.setValue(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "usa.png"), forKey: "image")
        threeActionButton.setValue(CATextLayerAlignmentMode.left, forKey: "titleTextAlignment")

        // Button #4
        let fourActionButton = UIAlertAction(title: "Four", style: .default, handler:{(action:UIAlertAction!) in
            print("Four")
        })
        fourActionButton.setValue(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "usa.png"), forKey: "image")
        fourActionButton.setValue(CATextLayerAlignmentMode.left, forKey: "titleTextAlignment")

        actionSheetAlertController.view.tintColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.317096545, green: 0.5791940689, blue: 0.3803742655, alpha: 1)

        var index = 100
        switch index {
        case 100  :
            // Show Actionsheet button 1 & 2
            actionSheetAlertController.addAction(oneActionButton)
            actionSheetAlertController.addAction(twoActionButton)
        case 10  :
            // Show Actionsheet button 4
            actionSheetAlertController.addAction(fourActionButton)
        case 5  :
            // Show Actionsheet button 3
            actionSheetAlertController.addAction(threeActionButton)
        default :
            // Show Actionsheet button 1 & 3
            actionSheetAlertController.addAction(oneActionButton)
            actionSheetAlertController.addAction(threeActionButton)
        }


        self.present(actionSheetAlertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: Thanks friend btw its showing Will never be executed warning. May I know how to resolve it?

Comment: Oh sorry, without the break. Apart from that index is set to 100 so it will show the warning either way